# Looking for free IDE/editor/plugins which will format source code according to JQuery Core Style Guideline

Tags: jquery, coding-style, editor

I am looking for any free editor/IDE/editor plugins which will format javascript code according to the [JQuery Core Style Guidelines](http://docs.jquery.com/JQuery_Core_Style_Guidelines)

Answer (score 0):

http://jetbrains.com/resharper/

ReSharper will help you with code formatting and styling. As of version 6.0 it has formatting for JavaScript/jQuery and can be customized for spacing and such.

Beyond that for readable source code, it sounds like they mainly run it through JSLint to cleanup and then minify.

ReSharper is a paid-for license, though they are kind and do give out free licenses to Students and Open-Source contributors. I'm not sure what the stipulations are on a Student license, but the Open-Source license is well respected - they review projects you work on to make sure you aren't another "giv us da kh0dz" programmer trying not to pay for good work.

I don't think there are any other free options that are going to do what you want.

I'm sure the hardcore dudes that build the jQuery Core have written their own code inspection/formatter utility. You could most certainly do that, but sometimes it's better just to shell out some money. :)

Comment: oops, I should have clarified. I wanted the free options. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: @RAbraham No problem. Check my edit here in a sec.

Answer (score 0):

The [Artistic Style](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html) utility has a lot of options when it comes to formatting source code.

Also if your editor of choice is scriptable it should be fairly easy to write a macro to run the utility from inside the editor.

As an example, here is [Zeus macro](http://www.zeusedit.com/zforum/viewtopic.php?p=731) that runs *Artistic Style* on the currently active file.